# Check for python3 presence inside the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python the first line of the script should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python{3}
```

Is there a way to do:

```
if python:
    #!/usr/bin/env/python
else:
    #!/usr/bin/env/python3
```

EDIT:

Running `python` in RHEL7 bring up python-2.7.5 (default).

Only running `python3` will execute python3-3.6.8 on my RHEL7.

Comment: What do you mean by `In python the first line of the script should be #!/usr/bin/env/python{3}`? As far as I'm concerned there is nothing like that.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez, to indicate it is `python` script, not a `Perl` one or a `shell` one.

Comment: @Igor The first line of a python script should _not_ be that.  That's not a python thing.  That's just a `bash`/whatever other unix shell thing.  It tells the **shell** what _interpreter_ to use, it's called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (short for hash `#` bang `!`).  It's _only_ a thing for unix/linux/etc. systems, nothing to do with python at all.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, but my question is not about that. It is about dynamically switching between `python` and `python3` where people has to work with both on 2 different environments.

Comment: @Igor You should probably use a library like [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/) for compatibility between python2 and python3.  See: https://six.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

None of those are correct. The correct command is `/usr/bin/env` and the argument to that, after a space, is the name of the actual interpreter you want it to look up.

Your question is a bit of a "turtles all the way down" problem. You have to know what command you want to run. You could of course create yet another tool and call it something like `py3orpy` but then you need to know that *that* exists in the `PATH` before you try to ask `env` to find it.

I would expect us to *eventually* converge on `python`; if you can't rely on that, perhaps the least error-prone solution is to figure out what's correct for the target system at installation time, and have the installer write a correct shebang. Or just install a symlink `/usr/local/bin/python3` if it doesn't exist already, and hardcode `#!/usr/bin/env python3` everywhere.

Comment: we are working under RHEL7 and will soon go to RHEL8, where python3 is the default. However we are also working under VM where python3 is not yet available. Is there a way to dynamically identify what should be run?

Comment: If you control the environment, of course you can. If you can force every VM to have `python3`, there you have it.

Comment: @Igor You should probably use a library like [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/) for compatibility between python2 and python3.

Comment: @tripleee, I wish. But it is not up to me. I can fix my VM, but not the one generated. Besides, we have to maintain compatibiliyu.

Comment: @Rocket This isn't about Python 2 interoperability at all, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, what? Extra dependencies? In my environment - more PITA... ;-)

Comment: I added another paragraph about fixing the shebang at installation time.

Comment: @tripleee, the other thing is - RHEL makes it python3, I guess for historical reasons to differentiate with python. And so makes it harder to maintain compatibility.

Comment: @tripleee, I understand. We use python scripts to generate some C++ code which will be then compiled into the binary. Anmd so, those scripts are called from the `makefile`s, - not the installer thing.

Comment: @Igor Wait, so is the problem is that you are not sure if the executable is _named_ `python3` or `python`?  In both scenarios, is it python 3.x?  Or is one of them python 2.x?  In most systems I've used `#!/usr/bin/env python` works fine to load the "default" python version.  I haven't used RHEL in a while, but I would assume that both RHEL 7 and 8 would have a `python` executable that loads whatever the default is.  If one system has a default of 2.x and another 3.x, then that's when you'd need something like `six` to handle this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, not, both scenarios are different - see edit to the OP.

Comment: @Igor OOOOOH!  I see now!  I'm sorry :-P

Comment: If you are using a Makefile anyway, let `make` figure out which interpreter to run, and ignore the shebang. If you are really enterprisey, use something like `automake` to generate a `Makefile` with the correct command to invoke a Python 3 interpreter on the target system, but if you are not already using Automake for other reasons, it's humongous overkill for this tiny problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I recommend this at all, but it does work:

```
#!/bin/bash

_=""""
if [[ -x '/usr/bin/python3' ]]
then
    exec /usr/bin/python3 "$0" "$@"
elif [[ -x '/usr/bin/python' ]]
then
    exec /usr/bin/python "$0" "$@"
else
    echo "No python available"
    exit 1
fi
"""

import sys
sys.stdout.write("you made it\n")
```

Can't do `from __future__ import print_function` because it has to be the first line of python.

Principles here are to use `bash` to do the executable detection but also make it valid python so you can just re-execute with the python interpreter on the same file.